Understanding equicontinuity in asymptotic normality with nonsmooth objective functions
I am working on the normality of extremum estimators with nonsmooth objective functions. Assume that my objective function is $Q_n(\theta)$, where $n$ is the sample size. I denote by $\hat \theta_n$ the extremum estimator that maximizes $Q_n$. The function exhibits discontinuity at some $\theta$ (a finite number of points).
As usual, assume that $Q_n(\theta)$ uniformly converges in probability to some nonstochastic $Q_0(\theta)$ that is twice continuously differentiable and is maximized at a single point $\theta_0$. I want to show that $\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_n - \theta_0) \overset{d}{\to} N(0, V)$, where $V$ is the asymptotic variance.
I use Theorem 7.1 of Newey and Macfadden (1994). They claim that one can work with the approximation:
$$ Q_n(\theta) - Q_n(\theta_0) \approx D_n'(\theta - \theta_0) + Q_0(\theta) - Q_0(\theta_0),$$
where  $D_n$ is the (approximation) of the derivative of $Q_n$ at $\theta_0$. This result is useful because inference can be conducted with the approximation that does not exhibit discontinuity (everything will be as usual). However, one important condition for using this result is that the approximation error is negligible:
\begin{equation}
R_n = \dfrac{\sqrt{n}\{Q_n(\theta) - Q_n(\theta_0) - D_n'(\theta - \theta_0) - (Q_0(\theta) - Q_0(\theta_0))\}}{\lVert \hat \theta_n - \theta_0\rVert} = o_p(1)
\end{equation}
Their justification for the previous condition is that $Q_n(\theta) - Q_n(\theta_0) - D_n'(\theta - \theta_0)$ goes to 0 faster than $\lVert \hat \theta_n - \theta_0\rVert$ (by the definition of the derivative). Similarly $Q_0(\theta) + Q_0(\theta_0)$ goes to 0 faster than $\lVert \hat \theta_n - \theta_0\rVert$ (the derivative of $Q_0$ is zero at $\theta_0$ because $\theta_0$ is a maximize of $Q_0$). Moreover, the numerator is bounded. I Understand these three arguments but do not see how they imply the above condition.
More specifically, if $A_n$ goes to zero faster than $B_n$ and that $\sqrt{n} A_n$ is bounded, how does this imply that $\frac{\sqrt{n}A_n}{B_n} = o_p(1)$?
